# Accessing value from one form to various form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have Three Forms in my windows application using c#. I want to access values from Form 1 to other Form(2,3). Means getting value on Form 1 and accessing this value to other page using simple function.
The form design is,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9sLI.jpg)

In blank text box user gives the value in string and am storing it in another string variable. Code is look like below;

```
public string comp="";
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comp = textBox1.Text;
        }
        public string getcomp()
        {
            return comp;
        }
```

The above getcomp() function am accessing on Form 2 and Form 3 on Button Click Event.
Please help me to solve these question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Form1
    `public static string comp`;

Form2  `MessageBox.show(Form1.comp);`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the function `getcomp()`, defined in **form1**, from **form2**, right?

The function is already declared as `public` meaning it shall be visible to the other forms. So by calling `form1.getcomp()` you can fire it and get the return value from any other form. This of course only works if you have an **instance of form1** in your application!

If not, for example if you disposed **form1** after opening/showing **form2**, you can't reach it like this, since there is no object you can call the function on. To still do so you could declare `getcomp()` as `static`. Doing so makes the function visible to all other forms even if there is **no instance of form1**.

But since the function has no real relationship to any of that forms I would strongly recommend to **put it in another class all forms can reach**.

Feel free to read some tutorials about scopes of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Declare a new variable in form2 where you can put the value of string comp from form1.

```
String comp2;
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
comp2 = form1.comp;
```